# is there anyway to scan I2C using pure Python libraries

Tags: python, i2c

I am trying to write a script which will scan **I2C** interface and check what slaves available. 
The only way I saw so far is by command `i2cdetect -y 1` which will list available **I2C** slaves. 
Is there any python library for doing that ?

Answer (score 2):

Any method of I2C scanning has risks.  Look at the man pages for the i2c_detect command.

Here is a simple method using (my) pigpio.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import pigpio

pigpio.exceptions = False # handle errors

pi = pigpio.pi()

for bus in range(2):
   for x in range(0x08, 0x79):
      h = pi.i2c_open(bus, x)
      if h >= 0:
         s = pi.i2c_read_byte(h)
         if s >= 0:
            print("device {} found on bus {}".format(x, bus))
         pi.i2c_close(h)

pi.stop()
```

Comment: read and even quickwrite methods can lock up the i2c bus, or slow it way down.

Answer (score 1):

The [Adafruit Blinka](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_Blinka) library implements an i2c scan function.

```py
import board
import busio

i2c = busio.I2C(board.SCL, board.SDA)
print(i2c.scan())
```